# Disable Javascript execution on specific pages (HTML/PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, security, header

is there any HTTP-header to disable Javascript for a specific page?
My website delivers user-generated HTML-content (that is why I cannot just use `htmlenitities`) and I would like to prevent scripting (JavaScript injections).

I already use HttpOnly-cookies being set for authentication on the main domain only, while user content is only displayed on subdomains where the cookie cannot be read.
The problem is that there are still too many possibilities to execute JavaScript - for example using event attributes like `onclick` and Internet Explorer has even a property in CSS to allow JavaScript executions (`expression`) which I had never heard of before. Another interesting idea I have read of, was about throwing an exception in order to block the code following.
One more idea would be defining a list containing all allowed tags and additionally an array with each allowed attribute name but this is very hard work and I guess this would not cover all possible injections.

I guess I am not the only person having this problem, so does anybody know a possiblility covering **all** possible harmful code - at least in modern browsers?

A simple imaginary header similar to `X-Scripting: disabled` would make life so much easier!

Comment: Have you ever thought of blocking `script` tags and certain attributes in user input?

Comment: That's what I meant by: "One more idea would be defining a list containing all allowed tags and additionally an array with each allowed attribute name but this is very hard work and I guess this would not cover all possible injections." (So I would for example allow harmless tags like "div" or "span" and disable attributes like "onclick", "onmouseover", but this would not cover all injections since browsers have different, browser-specific attributes and properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an experimental HTTP header called the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy) that allows you to control where JavaScript comes from, which can make XSS impossible. However it is currently only supported by Chrome and Firefox.

It is a good idea to enable HttpOnly-cookies,  however this will prevent exactly **ZERO** attacks.  You can still exploit XSS by [reading CSRF tokens, and carrying out requests with an XHR](http://namb.la/popular/tech.html).

There are many ways of obtaining XSS, and a Vulnerability Scanner like [<s>ShieldSeal</s>](https://shieldseal.com/) (down) will find (nearly) all of them. [Skipfish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/) is an open source vulnerability scanner that is very primitive,  but its free. This is how most web applications deal with wide spread vulnerabilities. (I work for ShieldSeal and I help build their vulnerability scanner and I love my job.)

When an issue is found you should use `htmlspecialchars($var)` or `htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES)` to sanitize input. `ENT_QUOTES` can prevent an attacker from introducing an `onclick` or other JavaScript event.

Comment: The only problem is that users should be as free as possible in generating their HTML-content, but without executing dynamic client-side code. SQL-injections or PHP-injections are not a problem because the code is stored in a database, not in .php-files and all parameters are cleaned before any use in SQL-statements. As for example there are necessary attributes like `src` for `img`-tags I cannot simple use `ENT_QUOTES` and sanitize all input. But I will read more about the Content Security Policy, to secure my site at least for Firefox/Chrome-Users.

Comment: @Birk oah I misread that,  then you do want to use HTMLPurifier.   Also you should usually sanitize at the time of use, so sanitize on output for xss.  However, HTMLPurifier uses a lot of resources,  so you should probably use that before inserting to the database.

Comment: @Birk, you might also want to check out the Google Caja project for safe embedding of HTML/CSS. https://developers.google.com/caja/

Comment: @Mikey link to "ShieldSeal" is down